# Edit url using .htaccess and remove query name

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am making an example app with my own routing system. It is working on GET request and 'action' variable.

My problem is look of url:  `localhost/routing/index.php?action=home/login`

How to remove that index.php?action=, so url will look like "localhost/routing/home/login"?

***I want to put `.htaccess` in "routing" folder!***

Comment: It might be useful for your routing system : [http://www.indexhibit.org/tutorials/getting-started/enable-clean-urls/](http://www.indexhibit.org/tutorials/getting-started/enable-clean-urls/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /routing/index\.php\?action=([^\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /routing/index.php?action=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot, even if I lost 6 reputation on this question :(